# IOS remove downloaded file in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I developed an Ipad app which download different kind of files, but after a week or some days the downloaded files are removed and the app that open the file can find it anymore.

Could anybody help me, Where should I save downloaded files in my app to avoid that the file came automatically deleted?. IOS usually remove downloaded files after certain time?.

I already read [this apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

I know that maybe is not something complicated but I can't figure out why the file is removed If anybody can help me I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put data cache files in the /Library/Caches
>   directory. Examples of files you should put in this directory include
>   (but are not limited to) database cache files and downloadable
>   content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map apps. Your
>   app should be able to gracefully handle situations where cached data
>   is deleted by the system to free up disk space.

Most probably you are using caches/temp directory which the system can clear contents of in case of low space. To avoid deletion use Documents Directory.

If you are already storing in documents directory, then the file can appear missing if you are storing its hardcoded path , which can change during app update. Try storing relative path and log the contents of your documents directory to see [what files exist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3).

Comment: Hello, the file has been downloaded in this directory /var/mobile/Applications/[a-long-number-here]/Documents/example1.pdf

Comment: Is this directory fine to save the document?

Comment: yes,it is , do you have any code which clears up the documents directory contents ?

Comment: no, I don't but I the app update every week with new releases and maybe the [a-long-number-here] change every update?. Now I am storing the hardcoded path. I'm going to change to relative path. To check if it is the problem

Answer (score 0):

save the files in your local sqlite db, data core or if you can serialize them with the standard user defaults